# using $gte and $lt for picking different rages of a specific field value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to pick documents with cost fields between 0 and 5 then trying to pick documents with cost ranges between 10 and 15. For this, I'm using `MongoDB aggregation`

```js
    const something = await dummyModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          fieldA: {
            $in: arryOfIds,
          },
          cost: {
            $or: [
              { $gte: 0, $lt: 5 },
              { $gte: 10, $lt: 15 },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

With the above approach, I'm getting this error from mongoose.

```sh
"message": "unknown operator: $or",
```

Any Idea on this to pick ranges in `MongoDB` using `mongoose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with `find` query.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "fieldA": {
    "$in": arryOfIds,
  },
  "$or": [
    {
      "cost": {
        "$gte": 0,
        "$lt": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "cost": {
        "$gte": 10,
        "$lt": 15
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXJLv1lH75G)

Comment: For other people that are in the same situation as me, this solution is also applicable inside aggregation pipelines. Tank you, saved lots of effort ;)